# TNS-01190: The user is not authorized to execute the requested listener command

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, listener

Oracle 11g Release 2
Oracle Linux Enterprise 5.10

```
[oracle@dub-ImrORA3 scripts]$ id oracle
uid=502(oracle) gid=502(oinstall) groups=502(oinstall),503(dba),504(oper)           context=user_u:system_r:unconfined_t
```

We recently changed the oracle id to 502 and the group oinstall to 502.

Everything under the $ORACLE_HOME/bin is owned by oracle:oinstall

Since this change we can only connect locally to the database using IPC. When we try to connect remotely using TCP we the error => ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed

When the oracle user tries to stop the LISTENER we get the TNS-01190 error.

```
[oracle@dub-ImrORA3 bin]$ ls -al lsnrctl
-rwxr-x--x 1 oracle oinstall 153535 Nov 26 09:45 lsnrctl
```

Is this an ownership/permission issue? How to resolve?

Comment: Did you stop the listener and database processes before changing the file ownership and uid/gid of the user/group? Have a look with `ps`. If not, that'll be the problem - the running processes would be horribly confused.

Comment: Yes, we stopped the listener and database before change ownership. And we were able to bring the database back up.

Comment: Enable listener logging, then edit the question with the relevant error messages/information

Comment: The last message in the listener log is from Jan 30th.

Comment: so how did you go about changing ownership of all of the files in `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$ORACLE_BASE`? Some are owned by `oracle:dba`, some `oracle:oinstall` and it varies by directory - did you do a blanket `chown -R` or did you do it properly?

Comment: I did a blanket chown -R, which I think is the problem.

Comment: Almost certainly. Your best bet is to get a file listing from a similar server and write a small script to set the correct permissions, or do a reinstall. Not much more we can do to help. In the first instance I'd probably stop the DB, kill the listener, then do a blanket `cd $ORACLE_HOME; chown -R oracle:dba bin lib lib32 network ` - anyway, you've messed it up by taking shortcuts

Comment: Got it fixed. Changed owner of oradism to root:oinstall and rebooted server. DB started, but not listener. Got different error message: ERROR:  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=IMR1))). Changed IMR1 to IMR0 then listener started successfully. Wish I understood this issue better. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Some of the processes need to be owned by root so that they can do particular stuff that only root can do.  By changing the whole directory to oracle:, you stop the processes from being able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an issue with owner and group of lot's of files in oracle home. Most files are of oracle:oinstall but not all. Some are owned by root and some owned by nobody.

A safer solution for this would be

```
find -user {old_uid} |xargs chown {new_uid}
find -group {old_gid}|xargs chgrp {new_gid}
```

and yes, this should run as root.